# Access SharePoint 2016 API on-premise with oAuth2 in .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

We have an old SharePoint 2016 environment hosted on-premise which we would like to access via the API (reading list items for example). To do this, you can use a nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint2016.CSOM . Unfortunately, this is a closed-source .NET Framework package and we are using .NET (7). Downgrading to .NET Framework is an absolute no-go for us.

How can we communicatie with the SharePoint API? There is a little bit of documentation on the API itself, but the biggest challenge is authorization. We received a clientid/clientsecret created within SharePoint (not Azure AD) and are trying to retrieve a token. But there isn't any documentation on that.

Does anyone have a hint on how we can use oAuth2 authorization to access the on-premise SharePoint 2016 API? Help is much appreciated, thanks!